# How would I add a border around my textview and create two tabs? Android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

My problem is that I cant get a border around my textview. I want to simulate a basic texting app. Also, how would I add tabs that allow you to just slide or press them? Thank YOU in advance!

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView
        android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
         />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayou
```

JAVA:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendMessage(View v){

    EditText editMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //get text from edittext and convert it to string
    String messageString=editMessage.getText().toString();

    //set string from edittext to textview
    textView.append(messageString+"\n");

    //clear edittext after sending text to message
    editMessage.setText("");


}

}
```

Comment: You can always put it in its own LinearLayout tag and specify the border there. I'm not sure what the second part of your question is asking so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks.. I want to have two tabs(Add and Inbox) at the top. and if its possible, I want to let the person slide the screen over to change tabs. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

you could try using setting a background on text view and just set the background as an image the suitible size and has a border.

Comment: If i am understanding the second part of your question properly  you would use a tabhost layout

Comment: What api level are you using ?

Comment: My target API is 17, but minimum is 14.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement tabs is using a TabHost/TabWidget as user1934637 mentioned. The Android developer guide covers this pretty thoroughly:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/tabs.html

Comment: How would I implement it in this case? The one on the website does it when its own class...

Comment: I think the guide explains it pretty clearly. You have to create an Activity for each tab (which is logical since each tab should be able to stand alone as its own page). The TabWidget in the layout allows you to navigate between these three activities. In your case, you create an activity for each of `Add` and `Inbox` and define a TabWidget in your layout to switch between the two.